# Javascript - Shared Pointer Paradigm

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, garbage-collection, shared-ptr

So, I'm writing an API in Javascript. The ideal requirements include that it support a structure like so:

- There are two classes: `class Core`, and `class Public`. Both have member `id`.
- There cannot exist multiple instances of `Core` with the same `id`, but each must have a unique `id`; however, there may be any number of `Public` instances with the same `id`.
- `Public` instances each have a single reference to the instance of class `Core` with the corresponding value for `id`.
- `Core` instances should be garbage collected as soon as the last `Public` instance pointing to it is garbage collected.
- Thus, when a new `Public` instance is created and given an `id`, it gathers and assigns its reference to either the existing `Core` instance, if one exists, or a new instance of `Core` if not.

and preferably (though not absolutely necessary):

- When the last reference to a `Core` instance is dropped, a method on it is run (i.e., a destructor)

Also, as I'm writing this in ES6, WeakMaps, WebAssembly, and any other modern JS API is permissible in an answer.

Is this structure possible in Javascript? If so, what would be the structure of such an implementation? Or, is this completely out of the scope of Javascript's capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this structure possible in Javascript?

Yes it is. However you cannot intercept garbage collection in any way, if all the references to an object got lost it will disappear silently, no one will notice it. Therefore if you want to notice it, you have to cause it explicitly:

```
 class Reference {
   constructor(to) { 
     this.to = to; 
     to.link();
   }

   free() { 
     this.to.unlink(); 
     this.to = undefined;
   }
 }

 class Referenceable {
   constructor() {
     this.count = 0;
   }

   link() { this.count++ }
   unlink() {
     if(!(--this.count)) {
       // your last words
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: True. I guess I hoped I could fight the obvious! :) As of now I've implemented it so that `Core` instances are cached in a queue with a max size. When `Public` instances need their respective `Core`, either the respective one is found and promoted to the top of the queue, or one is created and queued, dequeuing / deleting the oldest entry. I didn't want a queue, but I suppose it'll work for my purposes. Thanks!